# How to change the CSS of page dynamically based on value?

Tags: javascript, css

We have a SharePoint site. We are fetching a value on MasterPage via javascript and depending on the value we want to change the CSS file.

Example:-

Say value = 1 then change the CSS file reference to CSS1.css (turns site color to red)

Say value = 2 then change the CSS file reference to CSS2.css (turns site color to green)

Is this possible? Any reference?

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var clientContext = null;
    var web = null;
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");
    function Initialize()
    {
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    this.list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Images");
    clientContext.load(list, 'Title', 'Id');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListLoadSuccess), 
    Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
    function onListLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
        alert("List title : " + this.list.get_title() + "; List ID : "+ this.list.get_id());
    if (this.list.get_title()="new site")
      {
    here I need to apply CSS1
      }
    else
    {
    apply CSS2

}
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }</script>​
```

Comment: Possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: can you post your javascript code? also does the css file name depend on the value that you get via javascript. its not necessary , but it avoid **alot** of `if` blocks

Comment: is it only to change the color of website?

Comment: To change color of particular DIV tags...

Comment: if you are very sure this is what you want to do (rather than just have both styles and switch classes on a top level element) then you could have a request parameter for the style you want and reload the page with a param, which the server could use to pick a stylesheet.

Comment: have both styles and switch classes on a top level element? Can you explain please

Comment: use jquery add/remove class - the simplest solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you are planning on switchiing stylesheets, you would have a stylesheet loaded somewhere in the head of the  page, like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="css-placeholder" type="text/css" href="default.css"/>
```

Use this JS:

```
var stylesheet = document.getElementById('css-placeholder');
if (this.list.get_title()="new site") {
    stylesheet.href = "css1.css"
} else {
    stylesheet.href = "css2.css"
}
```

Comment: Do I then need to refresh the page so that it gets the effect of new css?

Comment: No, you don't need to.

Comment: Where do I place this code? ins cript tag, just before closing head?

Comment: Hi, can we change the css style directly instead of the files?

Answer (score 1):

You may do it as LShetty offered, or by changing the className of the body:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bla!</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            body.red { background-color:red; color:green }
            body.red > div { border-style:solid; border-color:yellow; }

            body.blue { background-color:green; color:red }
            body.blue > div { border-style:solid; border-color:blue; }

        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function SetStyle (value) {
                document.getElementById('body').className = value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class='body' id='body' >
        Some content here 
        <div> Some coneten here too</div>
        <select onchange='SetStyle(this.value);'>
            <option value='red'> Red Style </option>
            <option value='blue'> Style Blue </option>

        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isnt it possible to change the css file reference?

Comment: Of course it is possible.  see LShetty 's answer :-)